# Hide main.html from header redirection

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a php file which redirects to main.html using header.
I need to hide the `main.html` from the url which looks like 'https://mywebsite.com/main.html`

So that, it looks like `https://mywebsite.com` while displaying the content of main.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if main.html has been sent in original request then redirect to home page
# THE_REQUEST variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser
# and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /main\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^main\.html$ / [L,R=301,NC]

# load main.html for landing page
RewriteRule ^/?$ main.html [L]
```

Comment: Why are you using `THE_REQUEST `instead of `REQUEST_URI`?

Comment: Added explanation and reason of using `THE_REQUEST`